# how to correctly write angular unit-tests against routing

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

So I have a directive that mimiks the href function except i wanted it to be doable with buttons, (say i dont like to css a tags).

```
app.directive('ngRef', function($location, $timeout){
    linkFn = function(sco,ele,att){
        ele.bind('click', function(){
//            console.log($location);
            $timeout(function(){
                $location.path(att.ngRef);
            }, 0);
        })
    }
    return linkFn;
})
```

Now I write a test to see if mockLocation is pathed to the new location upon click, so

```
describe('ngRef', function(){
    var mockLoc, mockTimeout, mockCompile, rootScope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('mySite')
        inject(function($injector){
            mockLoc = $injector.get('$location');
            mockTimeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
            mockCompile = $injector.get('$compile');
            rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        })  
    })

    it('should land on the page of the ngRef attribute on click event', function(){
        var elem = angular.element('<button ng-ref="/contact">Click</button>');
        expect(rootScope.activePage).toBe('HOME');
        mockLoc.path('/home')
        mockCompile(elem)(rootScope.$new())

        elem.trigger('click');
        rootScope.$apply();
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(rootScope.activePage);
            expect(mockLoc.path()).toBe('CONTACT');     
        }, 0)
    })
})
```

but now i noticed thatit always failed tests, what's wrong with my assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Angular 1.2.0 I think you need to load ngRoute in your test and make sure it's included in the configuration:

```
beforeEach(module('ngRoute'));
```

It would help if you included the output error message you get from the unit test.